# Creating a factory class?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework2

I found this snippet of code:

```
class WebsitesTableFactory extends AbstractModelFactory
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $dbAdapter = $container->get('bc_db');
        $tableGateway = $this->initializeTableGateway('websites', $dbAdapter, null, $container->get(Websites::class));
        return new WebsitesTable($tableGateway);
    }
}
```

What I have been used to is:

- implementing the `FactoryInterface` instead of extending `AbstractModelFactory`
- using `ServiceLocatorInterface` as a parameter for the `createService` function

How is this different from that implementation?

And what does the `::class` mean?

Zend Version is 2.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [PHP Class Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php)

`::class` returns the FQCN (Fully Qualified Class Name), e.g. "\Namespace\Path\To\Classname".

---

#### ZF2 - 3 Factories

In preparation for ZF3 it became common to use `__invoke(ContainerInterface $container)` instead of `createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceManager)`.

It was used as the default Factory you're used to was replaced with another that implements another Interface, though leaves room for the transition of ZF2 to ZF3.

A standard Factory class in ZF3 looks like this:

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;

class DemoFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        // Do your thing
    }
}
```

**Note:** a different `FactoryInterface` use-statement than in ZF2!

---

#### Upgrade everything

Clearly you're still using ZF2. I can strongly recommend you upgrade (or start upgrading) to ZF3. You could [read the migration guide](https://zendframework.github.io/zend-servicemanager/migration/), however I would suggest you simply update everything in a single fell swoop.

My suggestion would cause you a great deal of work (probably, depending on the size of your application) but everything would be up-to-date.

I recommend going into your `composer.json` and removing all version constraints, then update everything with a `composer update` to the latest versions. Then go from there, you'll have endless errors to fix because of outdated stuff.

(There might be exceptions of packages that cannot be upgraded, for whatever reason, please note they might cause unintended version constraints if you *do* follow the above advice).

---

#### You might need help

On the other hand is the thing that you don't know about `::class` returning a FQCN, which is pretty basic and standard to use and has been for quite some time (since PHP 5.6 (released [halfway 2014](http://php.net/supported-versions.php)) if memory serves). As such, the above might be too overwhelming and I would recommend you seek help from a colleague or someone with more experience with Zend Framework development.

Comment: Thank you for this, this clarified a lot of things to me. I wish there were comments as to why my question was downvoted, I have tried searching for answers first of course before resorting to here, thinking there could be other reasons aside from that, why someone wrote the factory class that way. Yesterday for some reason when I searched for `::class` it showed me  confusing articles and did not include a link to the PHP manual. Anyway, thank you @rkeet for answering my question regardless, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. Please note that I stand by that you're going to need help. Using class constants has been the norm for years, so you need to either/or/all: 1) start learning a lot of PHP and coding patterns (either new or catch-up); 2) get yourself a good editor, that helps a lot (I can recommend PhpStorm); 3) get help, either freelance or additional employees or friends (depending on where you have this project) with knowledge of ZF2/. Because ZF has a real high learning curve and "just doing/trying stuff" will only get you so far.